# main activity gets white screen after slpash screen

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

I am creating an app in which i have created **navigation drawer** in **one** project and **splash screen and one more random activity** in **second** project. 
So I am **trying to merge** them. I **have set the splash screen** and random acitvity so **merge have done properly.**

Then I have set a **button** on **random activity** which **redirects** to **main activity(here is homeActivity)** but when I **click on button** its get **white screen**.

In homeAcitivity I have **used navigation Drawer** as **I already mentioned** so how can I solve the white screen issue on mainActivity???
I have seen some question here but I am not getting my solution....

using android studion 2.1.2
gradle version 2.10

Thanks

**CODE**

here is mainActivity(here homeActivity)

```
public class homeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
ListView list;
String[] menutitles;
String[] menudescriptions;
int images[]={R.drawable.mouse, R.drawable.keyboard, R.drawable.filemanager, R.drawable.media, R.drawable.power};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Resources res = getResources();
    menutitles=res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    menudescriptions=res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listadapter adptr=new listadapter(this,menutitles,images,menudescriptions);
    list.setAdapter(adptr);
    onclick();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
 public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_mouse) {
        Intent intentu = new Intent("com.example.admin.pcremote.MouseActivity");
        startActivity(intentu);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_keyboard) {
        Intent intentu = new Intent("com.example.admin.pcremote.KeyboardActivity");
        startActivity(intentu);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_filemanager) {
        Intent intentu = new Intent("com.example.admin.pcremote.FilemanagerActivity");
        startActivity(intentu);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_media) {
        Intent intentu = new Intent("com.example.admin.pcremote.MediaActivity");
        startActivity(intentu);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_power) {
        Intent intentu = new Intent("com.example.admin.pcremote.PowerActivity");
        startActivity(intentu);
    }else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(homeActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Do You Want To Exit?").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setTitle("Exit!!");
        alert.show();
    }

   DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

activity_main.xml(homeActivity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout        
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.admin.pcremote.homeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" /> 
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.admin.pcremote.homeActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is other activity
in this i have tried to navigate other activity its working but dont know with mainActivity

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ipInfo.this);
     builder.setTitle("Warning");
      builder.setMessage("IP address or port number cannot be empty!!!").setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                      }}).setNegativeButton("Continue Anyway", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         Intent inst = new Intent(ipInfo.this,homeActivity.class);//here is redirection of home activity
         startActivity(inst);
       }});
       AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
       alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_black_24dp);
       alert.show();
```

Splash screen

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_splash);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    Thread ssThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                StartAnimations();
                sleep(3500);
                Boolean isfirstrun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES",MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("first",true);
                if(isfirstrun){
                    Intent inst = new Intent(welcome_splash.this,install_server.class);
                    startActivity(inst);
                    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES",MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("first",false).commit();
                }else{
                Intent starthomeScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ipInfo.class);
                startActivity(starthomeScreen);}
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    ssThread.start();


}
private void StartAnimations() {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);


}
```

logcat is

```
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 574: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getObbDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x1356
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.startPostponedEnterTransition, referenced from method com.example.admin.pcremote.homeActivity.access$super
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 249: Landroid/app/Activity;.startPostponedEnterTransition ()V
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x135c
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalCacheDirs, referenced from method com.example.admin.pcremote.homeActivity.access$super
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 565: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getExternalCacheDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x13ce
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onEnterAnimationComplete, referenced from method com.example.admin.pcremote.homeActivity.access$super
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 145: Landroid/app/Activity;.onEnterAnimationComplete ()V
01-01 16:55:22.725 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x1411
01-01 16:55:22.735 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 537K, 9% free 8425K/9159K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-01 16:55:22.735 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.256MB for 1048588-byte allocation
01-01 16:55:22.745 4495-4499/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 8% free 9444K/10247K, paused 10ms+0ms, total 12ms
01-01 16:55:22.755 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 9444K/10247K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-01 16:55:22.755 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 11.501MB for 2359308-byte allocation
01-01 16:55:22.765 4495-4499/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 11748K/12615K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 5ms
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 19953: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 19953: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownViewTheme, referenced from method com.example.admin.pcremote.listadapter.access$super
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19710: Landroid/widget/ArrayAdapter;.getDropDownViewTheme ()Landroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x014a
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewTheme, referenced from method com.example.admin.pcremote.listadapter.access$super
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19720: Landroid/widget/ArrayAdapter;.setDropDownViewTheme (Landroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)V
01-01 16:55:22.775 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x01d4
01-01 16:55:22.805 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3414K, 32% free 8697K/12615K, paused 2ms, total 4ms
01-01 16:55:22.805 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.084MB for 589836-byte allocation
01-01 16:55:22.815 4495-4499/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 11K, 27% free 9262K/12615K, paused 11ms+0ms, total 14ms
01-01 16:55:22.815 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 258K, 29% free 9015K/12615K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
01-01 16:55:22.815 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.808MB for 1022412-byte allocation
01-01 16:55:22.825 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 21% free 10013K/12615K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-01 16:55:22.825 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 21% free 10013K/12615K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-01 16:55:22.825 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 12.001MB for 2300412-byte allocation
01-01 16:55:22.835 4495-4499/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 18% free 12260K/14919K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 4ms
01-01 16:55:22.845 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1396K, 19% free 12175K/14919K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-01 16:55:22.845 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 12.918MB for 1048588-byte allocation
01-01 16:55:22.855 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 18% free 13199K/16007K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-01 16:55:22.855 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 18% free 13199K/16007K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-01 16:55:22.865 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 15.168MB for 2359308-byte allocation
01-01 16:55:22.865 4495-4499/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 16% free 15503K/18375K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 3ms
01-01 16:55:22.895 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.design.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.drawableHotspotChanged
01-01 16:55:22.895 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16053: Landroid/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
01-01 16:55:22.895 4495-4495/com.example.admin.pcremote D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after reviewing all other layout files related to main activity we got the solution for our problem

**solution is** 
**Changed** in **content_main.xml** in **desing** view From **AppTheme.NoActionBar** to **AppTheme**
and its showing activity in normal way...